# Не могу считать 2 числа из текстового файла

Tags: c++, файлы

Мне нужно считать 2 числа из текстового файла, но почему-то `row` и `column` не получают нужные значения (в файле числа записаны). В чем проблема?

```
int main()
{
    int arr[rowMax][columnMax];
    int row;
    int column;
    string a;
    cout << "Enter the directory of the file you want to open:" << endl;
    getline(cin, a);
    ifstream Notepad(a);
    Notepad.open(a);
    if (!Notepad.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Wrong directory of the file " << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        Notepad >> row;
        Notepad >> column;
        cout << row << column;
        fillArray(arr, rowMax, row, column);
        processArray(arr, rowMax, row, column);
        showArray(arr, rowMax, row, column);
    }
    Notepad.close();
        system("pause"); 
}
```

Comment: а какие значения они получают?

Comment: ну я в блокнот вписал 5 5

Comment: так а в программе у них какие значения?

Comment: -85993460 , что то такое

Comment: Вот не надо обрезать инклуды, константы и т. п. Если бы не это, мы могли бы легко скопировать код себе и проверить.

Answer (score 2):

Да все тривиально.

```
ifstream Notepad(a);
```

Вы **уже** открыли файл. После чего опять пытаетесь открыть:

```
Notepad.open(a);
```

Файл **открыт**, но теперь, после неудачного *второго открытия* его состояние - fail, вот ничего и не читается, получаете мусор...

```
if (!Notepad.is_open())
```

Хотите убедиться? Вставьте строку с проверкой:

```
ifstream Notepad(a);
Notepad.open(a);

cout << Notepad.good() << endl;
cout << Notepad.fail() << endl;

if (!Notepad.is_open())
```